# Progress Bar increment while running

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have a program I created in Visual Studio that has a list of programs and checkboxes for each.  You select which programs you want, click a button, and then it silently installs without user interaction.  I'm trying to add a progress bar to this, but can't seem to get it working properly.

I start with *if...then* statements to find which ones are checked...

```
    If Chk_VC.Checked Then Install_VC()          'Visual C++ Redistributable 
    If Chk_dotnet.Checked Then Install_dotnet()     'Microsoft .Net Desktop Runtime
```

then run the functions to install the specific program(s)...

```
Function Install_VC()   'Visual C++ 2015-2022
    arg.FileName = "...installs\Microsoft\Framework\VC_redist_2015-2022_14.38.33130_x64.exe"
    arg.Arguments = "/install /passive /norestart"
    Process.Start(arg).WaitForExit()
    Return True
End Function

Function Install_dotnet()
    arg.FileName = "...\installs\Microsoft\Framework\Microsoft .Net Desktop Runtime\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.25-win-x64.exe"
    arg.Arguments = "/install /passive /norestart"
    Process.Start(arg).WaitForExit()
    Return True
End Function
```

I've tried both **ProgressBar1.PerformStep()** and **ProgressBar1.Increment(1)** in **button_click** and individual Procedures.  The progress bar only progresses after everything is done running.

So I thought I could try refreshing the progress bar or form itself with **ProgressBar1.Refresh()** and **Application.DoEvents()**, but still doesn't display properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

EDIT:
Created two checkboxes for testing, one with notepad and one with calc.

```
Sub Install_notepad()
    arg.FileName = "notepad"
    Dim x = WaitForProcess(arg)
    'Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub

Sub Install_calc()
    arg.FileName = "calc"
    Dim x = WaitForProcess(arg)
    'Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub

Private Async Function WaitForProcess(ByVal args As ProcessStartInfo) As Task
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
       Process.Start(args)
    End Sub)
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
End Function

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then Install_notepad()
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then Install_calc()
```

It opens two notepads or calcs depending on which one is "last" in the code, so for this instance, on Button_Click it opens two Calcs.  If I include Thread.Sleep(1000), it works fine (but the progress bar still doesn't).

Comment: If you want progress reports from the program installers then you will need to find out how to do that for each program. (I don't expect that to be available, but you won't find out until you ask the the program developers.) Or do you want a progress bar to count which ones are done?

Comment: The last one.  Just a progress bar to keep track of how many are done.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `WaitForExit()` on a different thread so it doesn't block your main UI...

Something like:

```
Sub Install_VC()   'Visual C++ 2015-2022
    arg.FileName = "...installs\Microsoft\Framework\VC_redist_2015-2022_14.38.33130_x64.exe"
    arg.Arguments = "/install /passive /norestart"
    Dim x = WaitForProcess(arg)
End Sub
Sub Install_dotnet()
    arg.FileName = "...\installs\Microsoft\Framework\Microsoft .Net Desktop Runtime\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.25-win-x64.exe"
    arg.Arguments = "/install /passive /norestart"
    Dim x = WaitForProcess(arg)
End Sub

Private Async Function WaitForProcess(ByVal args As ProcessStartInfo) As Task
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Process.Start(args).WaitForExit()
                   End Sub)
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
End Function
```